# Fastest way to delete a binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

What's the fastest way to delete a binary tree in C and why?
Is there a way to do better than this:

```
void deleteTreeUtil(struct node* node)
   {
       if (node == NULL) return;
       deleteTreeUtil(node->left);
       deleteTreeUtil(node->right);
       printf("\n Deleting node: %d", node->data);
       free(node);
    }

void deleteTree(struct node** node_ref)
{
  deleteTreeUtil(*node_ref);
  *node_ref = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore are reserved.  Don't make such names of your own.

Comment: The *fastest* way (presuming a sufficiently large tree) is to `fork()` a new process and create your binary tree in there. Then, when you're ready to delete, just `exit()` from that process and evaporate the entire memory space. Whether this maximum deletion speed justifies the other issues it causes is another question.

Comment: This is *not* your program's bottleneck.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, I think the semantics you are trying to expose are not the semantics of the `fork()` system call, as it makes a complete duplicate of the original process, making the modifications made by the child process unavailable to the parent, but spawning a new thread at each node when there are `left` and `right` children can make an imporvement in case you have several cpus/cores.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Modifications made by the child certainly are available to the parent - processes are obviously able to communicate with each other. As I said, whether this justifies the cost depends on the problem. If a program is regularly creating and deleting a large tree, it's entirely possible you might be able to decant the logic into a separate process without needing to communicate with the parent. Spawning threads isn't going to help with speed of creation or deletion, since access to the data structures `malloc()` and `free()` use will need to be serialized.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, I'm afraid the questions asks for an actually more efficient way to proceed.  You are planning to do this by `fork()`ing a new process at each node in the tree and you really thing this will be more effective?  Well, go ahead!!!

Comment: @LuisColorado: Where did I ever mention forking a new process at each node? I said forking a separate process for the entire tree. Read more carefully, please.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, either way, anything that spawns a new process is less efficient than doing it without creating a new process... anyway.  Even if you have to delete, you will be deleting the tree in the virtual memory space of the subprocess.  If you have to pass all this information for the parent to know how to delete the tree, you'll be finished just with the shown algorithm probably before the call to `fork()` returns.

Comment: @LuisColorado: What are you talking about? You don't "pass all this information to the parent to know how to delete the tree". The tree just vanishes. Doing it this way is unquestionably more efficient than manually deleting thousands of nodes, it's not a debatable point. OP wanted to know "the fastest way to delete" a tree, and this is it. As I said in the first comment, whether this justifies the other costs depends on the problem. There is nothing controversial in this, you're arguing with air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small optimization to improve performance for large trees:

```
void _deleteTree(struct node* node)
{
       if (node->left)
       {
             _deleteTree(node->left);
             free(node->left);
       }
       if (node->right)
       {
             _deleteTree(node->right);
             free(node->right);
       }
}

void deleteTree(struct node** node_ref)
{
     if (*node_ref)
     {
          _deleteTree(*node_ref);
          free(*node_ref);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach shown is pretty lean and fast, assuming the printf is removed (that part is *really* slow). I don't see a faster approach, assuming that each node is allocated individually and the nodes are singly-linked as suggested by the provided code.

If the tree nodes were doubly-linked, then a breadth-first traversal would be possible without recursion, reducing stack growth and potentially reducing execution time. If trees are being repeatedly allocated and deleted, then maintaining a pool of node structures (instead of alloc/free each time) would certainly save time on the allocation process (but might not speed up the delete).

Comment: In case of doubly-linked nodes and breadth-first traversal, we will incur cost of enqueue and dequeue too.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a tree i.e. free all the nodes in the binary tree you have to visit all the nodes once no matter what your traversal style(inorder/preorder/postorder) is. Algorithm wise there is nothing much to reduce the time complexity.

You can use some programming hacks and at most what you can try is you can go for iterative style but again that might not give you very significant increase in speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are **tons** of ways to speed up the deletion of a tree, this list is not exhaustive:

- **maintain a list of the nodes**, you can then free them sequentially (it saves the recursive function calls)
- play with the compiler's **optimization flags**
- store it's nodes in **automatic variables**, just return from the function declaring them and they're freed, well ... automatically :)
- **allocate all the nodes at once** in one big array of nodes, large enough to store the whole tree, then just free the array and you're done
- **don't delete it** and either reuse it or let it be freed at the program's exit

This leads to the following questions:

- How is implemented your tree?
- Is the tree of fixed size, known in advance?
- To what extent can you alter the structure and the creation process?
- Do you want to speed up the freeing time of some trees or do you want to reduce the algorithmic complexity of your freeing procedure?
- Why do you need to speed up the deletion process?